Quotient of K3 surface: complex vs positive characteristic
Let $f: X \to X$ be a non-symplectic automorphism of finite order of complex projective K3 surface $X$. (Recall: Non-symplectic means that the induced action on $H(X,K_X)=H^0(X, \Omega_X^2)$ is not trivial). Consider the quotient  $p: X \to Y:=X/ \langle f \rangle$.
In Lemma 4.8 (p 330) from Huybrecht's Lecture on K3 is claimed that $X/ \langle f \rangle$ is either rational or birational to an Enriques surface.
It is remarked that this follows using the Enriques classification
of surfaces. I would like to eloborate the argument in detail & discuss to which amount it extends to positive characertistic.
Think the most "elementary" approach in case of complex setting coming into my mind is firstly to base change along resolution of singularities of $Y$ in order to assume $Y$ to be smooth (...that's ok, as the statement is about birationality class).
Then in complex setting (that's appears to be the key insight) using Hodge decomposition the irrationality $q:= H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ equals $H^{0,1}(X)= H^0(X, \Omega_X)$, so the all birational invariants appearing in Enriques classification (=plurigenera & irrationality) are incoded at "$H^0$-level" in groups $H^0(X, \Omega_X^j)$.
Then we can exploit (...here we again need charactistic $0$) that for dominant map $p: X \to Y$ the induced maps $H^0(Y, \Omega^j_Y) \to H^0(X, \Omega^j_X)$ are injective
(...this should be basic, one way to do elementary it is to observe that  $\Omega_X \to (j_{\eta})_*\Omega_{K(X)/\Bbb C}$ is injective for $j_X: \eta_X \hookrightarrow X$ canon embedding of generic point and then the question becomes about injectivity of $\Omega_{K(Y)/\Bbb C} \to \Omega_{K(X)/\Bbb C}$; that's also injective since $K(X)/K(Y)$ is separable; that's also crucial, compare with positive char case below!) and this gives us estimations for Enriques invariants of $Y$ in terms of those of $X$, and we can invoke the Enriques classifiction table.
Firstly, is the argumentation correct so far? ("Easier"/slicker ways to see  injectivity  $H^0(Y, \Omega^j_Y) \to H^0(X, \Omega^j_X)$ of course welcome).
It seems, that the arguments above go through, but what makes me uncomfortable with the presented argumentation is that I seemingly nowhere uses that $f$ is non-symplectic. So maybe my argumention has gaps...
Next, the key question is what can be said about this Lemma 4.8 in Huybrechts' notes in positive characteristic of base field $k$ of algebraic K3 surface? To which extend is it still true?
First obvios problem is that in pos characteritic $q$  we generally don't have $q=H^0(X, \Omega_X)$. Furthermore, going through the argument above $\Omega_{K(Y)/\Bbb C} \to \Omega_{K(X)/\Bbb C}$ may not be injective due to inseparability phenomena.
So the question is to which amount the statement that the statement that the quotient $X/ \langle f \rangle$ of K3 surface is either rational or birational to an Enriques surface still holds in positive characertistic?
